# How to detect repeated values in array of integer and create a new one with them in java?

Tags: java, arrays

everybody, I would be very thankful if You could help me in this question. The point is I have initial array "a" with bunch of numbers, some of them can repeat many times, some of them - once. The task is to create a new array "b" which consists of repeated numbers. If any number from array "a" repeats more than once - in array "b" it must be reflected only once. The sequence of elements in a new array shoulb be the same as in the initial. 
For instance:

```
*initial array "a": 2 3 3 4 5 6 9 2 7 3 3  
new array "b": 2 3*
```

I have decided to generate array "a" randomly every time, it's without any difficulties, but as regards defining repretitions have some problems. The only thing I have done is found all repeated numbers.And the result I have right now is

```
*initial array "a": 2 3 3 4 5 6 9 2 7 3 3        
new array "b": 2 3 3 3*
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProcessingTool  {

public static int[] arrayCreatingMethod(){

    Random rand = new Random();

    int myArrayDim = rand.nextInt(50);

    int [] myArray  = new int [myArrayDim]; 

    for (int i=0; i<myArray.length;i++){

        myArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(100)); 

    }

return myArray;

}

public static int[] newArrayCreatingMethod(int[] a) {

    int[] d = new int [a.length];

    int k = 0;
    int repetitions = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){

         int j = i;
         int current = a[i];             

         while (j<a.length-1) { 


             if (current == a[j+1]) {

                 d[k] = current;    
                 k++;
                 repetitions++;
                 break;

             }


             else {

                 k=k-1+1;

             }

             j++;

         }

    }

    System.out.print("\n"+repetitions+"\n");

   System.out.println("\nArray d: ");

   for (int ww = 0; ww<d.length; ww++){

        System.out.print(d[ww]+" ");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone who found time and responded to me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. It navigates through every element in array `a` to check to see if it occurs more than once, and if it does, it adds it to a HashSet.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class IntCount {

    int [] a = new int [] {2,3,3,4,5,6,9,2,7,3,3};

    public IntCount()
    {
        Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i : a)
        {
            if (containsTwice(i))
                b.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b.toArray()));
    }

    boolean containsTwice(int i)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j : a)
        {
            if (j == i)
                count++;
        }
        return (count > 1);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new IntCount();
    }
}
```

Output: [2, 3]

Answer (score 2):

Using the proper classes simplifies this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class Reducing {

  public int[] reduce(int[] input) {
    Set<Integer> vals = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> recurrences = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : input) {
      if (vals.contains(i)) {
        recurrences.add(i);
      }
      vals.add(i);
    }
    vals.retainAll(recurrences);
    int index = 0;
    Integer[] recurs = new Integer[vals.size()];
    for (Integer i : vals)  {
      recurs[index++] = i;
    }
    return recurs;
  }

  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    Integer[] input = {2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 3};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reduce(input)));
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is flawed, as OP wants to filter all numbers, which recur at least once. In your JUnit example, '3' isn't recurring, so it must not be in the result array.

Comment: Ah, okay I thought that each number should be retained, not each number which occurred more than once. However using a linked data structure together with some set should be the proper way.
Probably using another set where only numbers are put in which are already contained in the first set would do the trick (this requires to iterate over the input). I'll fix the code this evening.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] findRecurringNumbers(int[] array){
    Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Integer i : array){

        Boolean recurred = map.get(i);
        //if current number is unknown ==> recurred = null
        //if current number occurred once ==> recurred = false
        //if current number occurred more than once ==> recurred = true

        map.put(i, recurred != null);
    }
    // as result, filter all entries' keys, where the corresponding value is TRUE
    return map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(entry->entry.getValue())
              .mapToInt(entry->entry.getKey()).toArray();
}
```

The above solution is tested with the following Junit test case:

```
@Test
public void testFind(){
    int[] a = {2,3,5,3,2,3};
    int[] expectedResult = {2,3};

    int[] recurrence = findRecurringNumbers(a);

    System.out.println("Recurrence: " + Arrays.toString(recurrence));

    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expectedResult, recurrence));
}
```

The console states:

> Recurrence: [2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,2,2,3,3,1,2};
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    int bcount = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){            
        for(int j=i; j<a.length;j++){
            if(a[i] == a[j] && i!=j){
                boolean flag = true;
                for(int q=0; q<bcount && flag; q++){
                    if(a[i] == b[q]){
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if(flag){
                    b[bcount] = a[i];
                    bcount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //display
    for(int i=0; i<bcount; i++){
        System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
    }        
}
```

I think your problem is printing out the number that you already printed out. So, just include a loop to test it. 

I hope it'd be helpful to you.